# Import all methods to a unittest file

Tags: python, unit-testing, parsing

I'm trying to figure out the best structure to write unittests for a file parser. My `parser.py` file looks like this:

```
import re
import sys
import glob
from datetime import datetime
import csv

def main():
    # does something

def normalizeGender(gender):
   # does something

def normalizeDate(date):
    # does something

def parseLine(record, delimiter):
    # does something

def formatRecords(record_list):
    # does something
```

etc...

I have `tests` dir, and inside a `parser_test.py` file that looks like this:

```
import unittest


class ParserTest(unittest.TestCase):
    # Returns True or False.
    def test(self):
            self.assertTrue(True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  unittest.main()
```

Now, if I want to test all the methods from my parser, should import them all at once? Something tells me they should be wrapped as a module of some sort.

Comment: `parser_test.py` should simply use `import parser`. The question, then, is how to make your test runner know to look in the directory where `parser.py` resides.

Comment: @user7496931, the answer to your question is probably _primarily opinion-based_

Answer (score 0):

The following answer is based on my tool preferences, and the practices that I usually follow:

1. I would use [`pytest`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/) to implement the tests
2. I would implement at least 1 test for every function: `test_normalizeGender`, `test_normalizeDate`, `test_ normalizeDate`, `test_parseLine`, `test_formatRecords`. However, in case you have if statement with multiple branching inside your code, make sure you try to cover the possible cases of those branches. In addition, if you have for loops, I will implement a test for no elements, one element, and multiple elements.
3. I will put all the test in the same file since they are related.

Keep in mind that when it comes to implementing unit tests, you are testing a unit, so you don't need to verify the functionality of all your parser in the same test. In addition, you should mock/patch objects, methods, or functions to facilitate testing.

I hope this helps.